# Chat Extensions on Facebook Messenger web app

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Facebook just launched Chat Extensions and open-sourced an example extension called TaskBot, which works in a chat between two people. The Github repo is [here](https://github.com/fbsamples/messenger-bot-samples/tree/master/chat-extensions), and the official docs are [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/guides/chat-extensions).

I tried to play around with it. Works fine within mobile app. But not within the web app (via messenger.com). When I try to edit a task list, I get redirected to the page https://messenger-taskbot.herokuapp.com/lists/{id} and I have the following message:

[image]

So I guess there isn't going to be Chat extensions for messenger.com on browser yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chat Extensions use webviews, and on "desktop" Facebook Messenger and messenger.com webviews open in new tabs. Chat Extensions rely on webview windows opening within the chat thread itself.

From the docs you linked to:

> When the user taps the chat extension's icon, it opens a webview-based
>   UI specified by the developer. The user can then create or select
>   content to be shared into the thread. The message shared into the
>   thread can contain images, links, and more.

So yes, it seems that chat extensions are meant to be mobile only.